# Quartic Equation having Galois Group as $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible quartic polynomial with $S_4$ as Galois Group. Let $\theta$ be a root of $f(x)$ and set $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. Now, the question is:

> Prove that $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 4 which has no proper subfields.

> Are there any Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 4 with no proper subfields?

As I have adjoined a root of an irreducible quartic, I can see that $K$ is of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

But, why does there is no proper subfield of $K$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$?

Suppose $L$ is proper subfield of $K$, then $L$ has to be of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. So, $L$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e., $L$ is normal. So the corresponding subgroup of Galois group has to be normal.

I tried working in this way but could not able to conclude anything from this.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: You're on the way. The group of the splitting field over $K$ has to be normal of order 6 in the group of the splitting field over $L$, which has to be normal of order 12 in $S_4$. Now, what do you know about subgroups of $S_4$?

Comment: yes, so, corresponding subgroup of order 12 is $A_4$ but, it is normal. So i do not get any contradiction with this :(

Comment: Keep going. You haven't used the "normal of order 6" part.

Comment: oh yes, but $A_4$ has no group of order 6, leave about being normal :) :) :)

Comment: There you go. Now, you can write it up and post is as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank You Sir. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. What's there to discuss?

Comment: I am sorry, That was by mistake.. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert the question to a problem in permutation groups.

Let $F$ be the splitting field of 
$$f(x)=(x-\theta_1)(x-\theta_2)(x-\theta_3)(x-\theta_4)$$
with $\theta=\theta_1$.

We were given that the Galois group realizes all the 24 permutations of the roots $\theta_i,i=1,2,3,4.$ Therefore
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q}(\theta))=\operatorname{Sym}(\{\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4\})
$$
contains automorphisms realizing all the six permutations of the other roots.

Galois correspondence then means that the claim is equivalent to:

> There are no subgroups $H$ properly between $\operatorname{Sym}(\{\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4\})$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(\{\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4\})$.

In other words, this is equivalent to proving that the obvious copy of $S_3$ inside $S_4$ is a maximal subgroup. Have you seen that? If not, can you prove it?

Comment: I do not know, but for some reason, i am not able to view maps as elements of permutation group :( I have to work on that i guess

Comment: No,the order of $S_{3}$ is $3! = 6.$

Comment: @Praphulla: If you know that $A_4$ is the only subgroup of index two in $S_4$, then you can use that simply by observing that $A_4$ does not have $S_3$ as a subgroup, because the latter contains odd permutations.

Comment: More generally, isn't it true for all $n$ that $S_{n-1}$ is a maximal subgroup of $S_n$?

Comment: @Gerry, sure. Assume that $S_{n-1}$ is the point stabilizer of $n$, and $S_{n-1}\subset H\le S_n$. Then $H$ moves the point $n$, and is thus transitive. But it also has full point stabilizer, so then has to be all of $S_n$. I didn't want to assume that all the readers have sufficient familiarity with group actions for that to be all clear. May be I worried too much (given that I identify a Galois group with its action on the roots anyway)?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you posted, and thanks for confirming maximality of $S_{n-1}$. So this means that if $f$ is irreducible of degree $n$ with Galois group $S_n$, and $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in some extension of the rationals, then the field generated by $\alpha$ has degree $n$ and no subfields but itself and the rationals. That's good to know.

Answer (score 8):

As has been remarked, the non-existence of intermediate fields is equivalent to $S_{3}$ being a maximal subroup of $S_{4}.$ If not, then there is a subgroup $H$ of $S_{4}$ with $[S_{4}:H] = [H:S_{3}] = 2.$ Now $S_{3} \lhd H$ and $S_{3}$ contains all Sylow $3$-subgroup of $H.$ But $S_{3}$ has a unique Sylow $3$-subgroup, which is therefore normal in $H.$ Hence $H$ contains all Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_{4}$ as $H \lhd S_{4}$ and $[S_{4}:H] = 2.$ Then since $H$ only has one Sylow $3$-subgroup, $S_{4}$ has only one Sylow $3$-subgroup, a contradiction
(for example, $\langle (123) \rangle$ and $\langle (124) \rangle$ are different Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_{4}$).

Comment: More generally, isn't it true for all $n$ that $S_{n-1}$ is a maximal subgroup of $S_n$?

Comment: That is true of course