# When is $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \cap \mathbb{R}$ equal to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm interested in necessary and sufficient conditions for a nonreal algebraic integer $\alpha$ to satisfy the equality above. I know that if $\alpha$ has prime degree then the equality holds, but I don't know whether this condition is also necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ has prime degree...

Comment: You have $\bar{\alpha}\in\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ for any root of unity at least, and $\alpha+\bar{\alpha}\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant nonreal $\alpha$.

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/464113/11619) for a discussion of one of the special cases in my answer (root of a quartic with Galois group $S_4$). Gerry Myerson was the first to make the key observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how useful this is, but a translation of this to the language of groups via Galois correspondence would go as follows.

Let $K$ be the splitting field of the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $\alpha$. IOW the normal closure of $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Let $G$ be the Galois group $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$,
and $G_\alpha$ the stabilizer of $\alpha$ when $G$ is viewed as a group of permutations of the zeros of $m(x)$. Let $\sigma$ be the restriction of complex conjugation to $K$.

Galois correspondence then tells us that $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]\cap\Bbb{R}$ is the fixed field of the group $H=\langle G_\alpha,\sigma\rangle$. Thus
$$
\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]\cap\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Q}\Leftrightarrow H=G.
$$

---

So for example if $\alpha$ is non-real and $G_\alpha$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, then the condition is satisfied. This is because $\sigma\notin G_\alpha$, and there are no subgroups properly between $G_\alpha$ and $G$. This happens for example when $\alpha$ is a non-real root of an irreducible quartic with Galois group $S_4$, because in that case $G_\alpha\cong S_3$ is a maximal subgroup.

If $[Q[\alpha]:\Bbb{Q}]$ is a prime, then $G_\alpha$ is automatically a maximal subgroup of $G$ also. So your observation fits into this as well.

Comment: OP actually has $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, though from context perhaps they mean $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: Makes no difference given that $\alpha$ is algebraic $\implies \Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]$.

Comment: Oh, of course. :/ Mea culpa on my part.

Comment: If I remember the basics of permutation groups correctly a point stabilizer is maximal, iff the action is primitive. This suggests that finding examples can be done by picking your favorite primitive permutation action together with a bit of inverse Galois theory.

Comment: Still thinking about locating an example where $G_\alpha$ is non-maximal.

Comment: By galois correspondence $G_\alpha$ is a maximal subgroup of the galois group of the splitting field iff $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ does not admit an intermediate field.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $X^4+2$. $G_\alpha=Gal(\mathbb Q(\alpha,i)/\mathbb Q(\alpha))$ is not maximal, because $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ admits the intermediate field $\mathbb Q(\alpha^2)$. Furthermore this is the unique intermediate field of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)/\mathbb Q$. In particular $\mathbb Q(\alpha) \cap \mathbb R = \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @MooS: That comment could be promoted to an answer.